# Como funciona o "vue-cli-service build" para criar meu arquivos index.html

Tags: vue.js, build

Tenho 2 projetos usando Vue v2.6.11
Ambos executo o Comando Yarn Build ( Script: "build": "vue-cli-service build" ) para  gerar para produção.

Ambos salvam em pastas separadas seus respectivos arquivos tanto .html quanto .js
(EX:  Public/Projeto1/... e Public/Projeto2/...)

No arquivo .html do **projeto1** se eu fizer alguma ateração por exemplo no

```
<title>Vue App Projeto1</title>
```

ele nao sobrepoe depois do bulid.

Porém, no **projeto2**, ao fazer essa alteração

```
<title>Vue App Projeto2</title>
```

depois do build ele volta para o padrão

```
<title>Vue App</title>
```

Alguem sabe me informar como isso esta realemente trabalhando?
tentei verificar os arquivos para ver as diferenças mas nao consegui entender muito e gostaria de aprender.

**Projeto2**
**vue.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    outputDir: "../../public/projeto2",
    publicPath: "/projeto2/",
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module.rules.delete('eslint');
    },
};
```

**babel.config.js**
`module.exports = {   presets: [     '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'   ] }`

**Projeto1**
**vue.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    outputDir: "../../public/projeto1",
    publicPath: "/projeto1/",
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module.rules.delete('eslint');
    },
};
```

**babel.config.js**
`module.exports = {   presets: [     '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'   ] }`

Espero ter explicado tudo direitinho... hehe
Agradeço a todos desde ja pela atenção. =D

Ja tentei alterar as pastas e reinstalar tudo.. mas nao obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não dá pra saber como está a estrutura de pastas do seu projeto atualmente, nem se utiliza o build padrão definido pelo `vue-cli-service`.

Mas supondo que não personalizou a rotina de `build` do projeto, então seria possível fazer essa mudança em seu projeto.

Dentro do diretório `public` é possível ver o arquivo "base" do html.

É neste arquivo que serão injetados as informações feitas durante o build.

Desta forma, para personalizar o title que é gerado, basta atribuir um valor padrão.

Vejo duas forma de fazer isso, sobreescrever diretamente o valor da tag html title de uma forma que ela não seja sobrescrita no momento do build. Isso vai fazer com que o texto seja sempre o mesmo, seria um valor estático.

Desta forma pode fazer a alteração diretamente no arquivo contido no diretório `public` do seu projeto gerado com o vue-cli.

Supondo que seu projeto foi gerado com vue-cli e que possui o nome: "projeto"

Então teria a seguinte estrutura de pastas:

```
.
├── _babel.config.js
├── _package-lock.json  
├── _package.json
├── _public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── index.html
└── _src
    ├── components
    ├── assets
    ├── App.vue
    └── main.js
```

Consigo ver duas soluções para o seu problema

Você pode editar o arquivo do diretório `public/index.html`

Para não sobre-escrever a tag title no momento do build, da seguinte forma:

Antes da mudança a tag title está com a configuracão:

```
<title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
```

Modificar para conter um título estático, que não será sobrescrito no momento do build da seguinte forma:

```
<title>Projeto</title>
```

Todas as mudanças acima foram feitas no arquivo `public/index.html`

A segunda forma é você sobre-escrever o valor que é interpolado no momento do build, na configuração padrão o vuejs utiliza o atributo `"name"` que está contido no arquivo `package.json`

Desta forma ao modificar o valor deste atributo no package.json no momento do build este valor será interpolado no arquivo `public/index.html` para a geração do build.

Como resultado final [após a rotina de build] o arquivo `index.html` gerado na pasta `dist` vai conter aquele valor. Então apenas substituindo o atributo name do `package.json` deve fazer o que deseja.

Para este resultado então edite apenas o `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "projetoblabla", //<-- Mudar esta linha
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  //resto do arquivo...  
}
```

Nesta mudança não será necessário mudar o arquivo index.html (pois ele já possui a configuração de interpolação).

Para outras personalizações consultar a documentação do [webpack](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options)